# Displaying time in 12 hour format in OpenBox?

Tags: linux, openbox

I have a version of Linux which lacks the ability to adjust the time format in a GUI. *I want it displayed in my panel in 12 hour format* Can I do this in bash? I am using openbox and sparkylinux.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You are saying that the time & date are already correct. So you just want to *display* the time in 12-hour format? You want *what* to display the time? The `date` command? Something else?

Comment: Maybe the tag is incorrect. I've used the date command to adjust the time before so I figured it may be related. I just want to display the time in 12 hour format, yes.

Comment: [Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time) and 12-hour display are not mutually exclusive things.  In addition to Celada's question, which you haven't in fact answered (given "in Bash" in the title), you need to [edit] your question to say unambiguously what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Hmn.. this sounds tricky; Although you can fix the time on bash level you may not see that reflected on the GUI. Every X windows should at least come with the date preference display; i don't understand why it lacks that.

Comment: "Closed as unclear", has three answers and is a popular question. Stackexchange, what are you doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In openbox, tint2 is being used as a panel. The configuration file to edit is `/home/user/.config/tint2/tint2rc`. Edit the date in the `# Clock` section like so:

```
time1_format = %I:%M %p
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, even after your clarifications I still don't understand what you are asking for but I'll take a stab at an answer anyway...

> I just want to display the time in 12 hour format, yes.

The `date` command has many format specifiers that allow you to request the time to be presented in a format other than the default. Consult the man page. `%I` is the hour in 12-hour format. Try for example:

```
date +%I:%M:%S
```

The title of your question says "Adjusting the time". But **adjusting** the time and **displaying** the time really have little to do with one another. Anyway, one doesn't adjust the time on most systems with Internet access anyway because it is adjusted automatically by [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @munchschair which modifies the time format in the `tint2` panel, the `conky` time format can also be set to display this format on the desktop itself.

Edit `/etc/conky/conky.conf` as root.  Replace `${time %T}` with this `${time %I:%M %p}`:

```
${goto 22}${font LCDMono:bold:size=18}${color3}${time %I:%M %p}${color}
```